# Mixing two stores into single, common one - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have my app (a boilterplate with few, my own features). It has a global store (build-in, came from the boilerplate), which looks like:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux'; //combine reducers from redux form
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import createReducer from './reducers';
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form'; //registration form


const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history) {
  // Create the store with two middlewares
  // 1. sagaMiddleware: Makes redux-sagas work
  // 2. routerMiddleware: Syncs the location/URL path to the state
  const middlewares = [
    sagaMiddleware,
    routerMiddleware(history),
  ];

  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
  ];

  // If Redux DevTools Extension is installed use it, otherwise use Redux compose
  /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
  const composeEnhancers =
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : compose;
  /* eslint-enable */

  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    fromJS(initialState),
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers)
  );

  // Extensions
  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
  store.asyncReducers = {}; // Async reducer registry

  // Make reducers hot reloadable, see http://mxs.is/googmo
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
      import('./reducers').then((reducerModule) => {
        const createReducers = reducerModule.default;
        const nextReducers = createReducers(store.asyncReducers);

        store.replaceReducer(nextReducers);
      });
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

Few days ago I've implemented a redux-form (it works great), but unfortunately it has an own, local store, which is not compatibile with the global one and looks like:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  form: reduxFormReducer
});
const store = (window.devToolsExtension
  ? window.devToolsExtension()(createStore)
  : createStore)(reducer);

export default store;
```

As far as I know, the store has to be global - the first one is, but the second one (for redux form) isn't.

## I would like to ask you

**How to mix these two stores into a single, common, global one?**

Thank you for any answers!

**Edit**: Redux form comes from: https://codesandbox.io/s/qx95rm7gG

React redux comes from: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

**Edit2**: Files hierarchy:

```
-app
--index.js
--store.js (first one, global)
--containers
---UserRegistration
----index.js
----store.js (the second one, local)
```

Comment: i think you meant a local `state` and not local `store`.

Comment: @Sag1v I'm kinda new to React, would be great if you could provide some full answer if you know how to solve my issue, I'm struggling through this since few days...

Comment: You didn't specify what exactly not working for you and from the code above it's really hard to see the big picture, no file names or hierarchy etc. i think you will get a good and a fast reply if you will upload a small example of your code to github as well.

Comment: In best case you should not use nested storages, and perform composing reducers in base store. In this case all reducer function will be separated by reducers group name in associated object. Don't forget check it in case of socket,io using for income events provider in saga.

Answer (score 0):

> but unfortunately it has an own, local store, which is not compatibile with the global one and looks like

This is not correct.  The redux-form reducer is a standard reducer like any other and just needs to be combined into your reducer (from `import createReducer from './reducers';`).

If you are already combining reducers in `createReducer` (I assume you are because of the `store.asyncReducers` in the hot reloading), then you just need to include the `reduxFormReducer` with `form` as the key, something like:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form';
import someReducer from './someReducer';
import someOtherReducer from './someOtherReducer';

export default function createReducer(asyncReducers = {}) {

  return combineReducers({
    form: reduxFormReducer,
    someReducer,
    someOtherReducer,
    ...asyncReducers
  });

}
```

If you share `./reducers/index.js` I can make this answer more specific.